# Is there a way to create an empty string in Dart besides using "" or ''?

Tags: dart

I'm looking for a safe and nice way, if any, to create an empty string in Dart that's not writing `""` or `''`.
For instance, lists have their own constructor `List.empty()`, but strings don't.
So, I'm asking if there is a better way than writing `""` or `''` to initialize an empty string.

Comment: What is the problem with `''`?

Comment: Please define "safe", "nice" and "better". There is obviously things like `"a".substring(0, 0)` or `"a".removeAll("a")`. As for `String` constructors, there is `String.fromCharCodes([])`. However, the language considers `""` or `''` as the *canonical* way to create an empty string, so there is no `String.empty()` constructor. The `List` constructor makes sense because it can create a fixed-length list, which there is no literal for (`[]` is growable). `String` doesn't have that kind of differences. In fact, you'll likely find that no matter what you do, you get the same *object*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't get why there was no `empty()` constructor for `String`s. However, it is still a bit strange to me to initialize class attributes with both literals and constructors. It makes me feel somewhat inconsistent. When I said safe, nice, and better I referred to the use of constructors, because sometimes there is validation logic inside that could help avoid errors, in a lean way. I know probably there is no way to avoid using literals to initialize atomic values, but sometimes there are workarounds (`double.isNan`) that just do the trick. It was worth asking. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways in creating `empty` strings

```
String str;
str = '';
str = "";
str = String.fromCharCodes([]);
str = 'a'.replaceFirst('a', '');

...

// and so it goes
```

And then you ask me "*Which would you use?*"

Of course I'll use the simple, elegant, and old school way: `''`

Answer (score 1):

The only way is

```
String name="";
```

The other way would be

```
String? name;
```

but this will be null not empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use Characters.empty.toString()